# How to set timer animation in Phaser ?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a sprite 'Bomb' when player touched it the 'Bomb' will be explode after 3 seconds, the time will show like animation or tween.that will be great pleasure to give example code.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? Any example code? Maybe something like this?

```
bombsprite = game.add.sprite(100, 100, 'mybomb');

// scale the bomb big/small 3 times (=3 seconds)
var bombtween = this.game.add.tween(bombsprite.scale).to({x: 1.1, y: 1.1}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.to({x: 1.0, y: 1.0}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.to({x: 1.1, y: 1.1}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.to({x: 1.0, y: 1.0}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.to({x: 1.1, y: 1.1}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
.to({x: 1.0, y: 1.0}, 500, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);

// after 3 times scale effect call explode function
bombtween.onComplete.add(doBombExplode);
bombtween.start();

function doBombExplode(scaleobj, tween) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/*if timer is not finished){
    bomb_timer = game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND / 2, set_time, this);
}
function set_time() {
     time_left -= .5;
}
```

if implemented correctly, this will go like this: 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0.